# Grails: findAllByTitle() as a search function?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to create a search for my Grails web application however I am having no luck in getting the results I want.  I'm currently using Grails 3.0.11, according to a post the searchable plugin is outdated but I couldn't get the elasticsearch plugin working either. I decided to try to use findAllByTitle("%test%"), I think it will work but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

A certain Title is saved to a local database and when searched in my views I want it to display a list of Titles saved for example if i were to type in T it would display "Test1", "Test2", and "Test3".  I've also tried executeQuery() with no luck.

**Title.groovy**

```
class Titles {

    byte[] branchImage
    String branchTitle

    static constraints = {
        branchImage(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024)
    }
    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

**TitleController.groovy**

```
class TitleController {
    def search(){
        def results = Title.findAllByBranchTitleIlike("%Test%")
        [results:results]
    }
}
```

**main.gsp**

```
<body>
    <div class="header-search">
    <g:form action="search">
        <g:textField name="search" class="search-field" value="search"/>
            <button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></button>
    </g:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**search.gsp**

```
<body>
    <g:each var="r" in="${results}">
        <li>${r.branchTitle}</li>
    </g:each>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use findAllBy... instead of findBy... . findBy... variant returns only a single result. See [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html).

Also I would rename field 'VarTitle' to 'varTitle' (or why not just 'title'). Java convention doesn't use uppercase field/method names.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. i made your suggested changes and i still can't get it to work.

Comment: after I search a Title when I am redirected to titles/search.gsp my search.gsp isn't rendering any titles that save to my local database. they are definitiely there and saved properly but i can't render the titles that i search for

Comment: What's your controller code like now? If it's still adding model variable results, try inserting ${results} in your gsp (anywhere) and see what gets printed out.

Comment: Its just returning [] an empty array?

Comment: Oh I didn't really notice that you are trying to do a like query. Change it to findAllByTitleILike('%Test%'). (Assuming you have renamed the field to 'title' by now.)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
class TitleController {
    def search(){
        def results = Title.findAllByVarTitle("%Test%")
        render(view: "search",model: [results:results])
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.
If you want all results instead of one, you need to use findAllBy.

Comment: hmm still hasn't done the trick! i changed it to findAllBy but the search.gsp still isn't displaying any results after i search something.

Comment: do i need to change my search.gsp then too? because now it is saying can't resolve symbol 'results'

Comment: Just realised you are using ${results} in your gsp. You should change that to ${r} since var="r"

Comment: do i need to change ${results} in the in=" " because it's still saying can't resolve symbol

Comment: I dont understand why it says that. Maybe a convention problem since you use VarTitle instead of varTitle. If that's not it, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Again just realised you domain class is supposed to be Title but you named is Titles

Comment: Ok so it's sort of working now. Lets say I have a title named "Test1" in my controller if I put findAllByTitleiLike("%test1%") it will show up, however, if i change that to "%quiz%" after i search test again now it doesn't show up..i thought that the "%___%" allowed for entry of any string which ignores case?

Comment: if by 'quiz' you mean a variable use "%${quiz}%". "%test1%" matches that exact string. If you want to insert a variable you can use syntax ${..} in a string delimited with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have typed 'class Titles', it's just a typo but if you copy pasted it from your code you have a typo in your code :)